Concatenating polars lazyframes overflows the memory
There are 4 csvs that I want to read in and then concatenate them. The csvs do not have exactly the same columns but the columns mostly overlap. I want the values to fill with NaN in case the column is present in one dataframe but not in the other

I am reading in 4 csvs with polars in a list called dfs

Each df in the dfs is 2.8 gb on the disk

df.estimated_size(unit = 'gb') return ~4.05 gb for each of the 4 dataframes in the dfs

Overall RAM consumption is 31.2 gb from htop

I try to concatenate the 4 dataframes in one using pl.concat(dfs, parallel = False)


Results:

If I read in the 4 dataframes using scan_csv (lazily) - My VM (128 gb) crashes
If I read in the 4 dataframes using read_csv (eager) - The pl.concat(dfs, parallel = False) takes the memory up from 31.2 gb to 50 gb.

I want to read the dataframes and concatenate without duplicating them as the read_csv option is doing. I thought scan_csv is my answer but it overflows even when I use parallel=False as per this answer
This is a fairly common scenario. What are the suggestions for polars users on reading multiple csvs and then concatenating them in a memory-efficient manner
The exact code I am using is as follows
ND = 4
with open("./features_to_keep.pkl", "rb") as f:
    CTK = pickle.load(f)

CTK = set(CTK) #columns to keep. I will be reading in only a subset of these columns

#Schema 
with open("./obj_cols.pkl", "rb") as f:
    obj_cols = pickle.load(f)
obj_cols = obj_cols.intersection(CTK)

with open("./bool_cols.pkl", "rb") as f:
    bool_cols = pickle.load(f)
bool_cols = bool_cols.intersection(CTK)


def read_features(i):
    fp = f"features_{i}.csv"
    cols = pl.scan_csv(fp).columns
    cols = list(set(cols).intersection(CTK))
    dtypes = {i:(pl.datatypes.Categorical if i in obj_cols else pl.datatypes.Boolean if i in bool_cols else pl.datatypes.Float32) for i in cols}
    df = pl.read_csv(fp, columns = cols, dtypes = dtypes, infer_schema_length = 0)
    # df = pl.scan_csv(fp, dtypes = dtypes, infer_schema_length = 0).select(cols)
    return df


dfs = []
#I do not use stringcache context manager in case I had used scan_csv
with pl.StringCache():
    for i in range(ND):
        dfs.append(read_features(i))
X = pl.concat(dfs, parallel = False, how = 'diagonal')



Are you saying the crash happens when .scan_csv() is called? Can you share the full Polars code you're using?

Yes exactly. I have updated the question to include the code

I wouldn't be surprised if using categorical data leads to a scan of the entire input to compute the categories before instantiating the LazyFrame (since the categories themselves are part of the schema, which needs to be known at every stage of a LazyFrame’s life). If all you're doing is concatenating, can you just leave everything as string? infer_schema_length = 0, with no dtypes, should be sufficient.

There are a couple things you could try. The first is converting your CSVs to parquet one at a time since CSV is a really inefficient way to store data and while polars will do its best with it, it isn't optimized for them. That might look like this:
for i in range(ND):
    fp = f"features_{i}.csv"
    df = pl.scan_csv(fp)
    cols = list(set(df.columns).intersection(CTK))
    cast_exprs = [
        pl.col(i).cast(pl.Categorical 
           if i in obj_cols 
           else pl.Boolean 
           if i in bool_cols 
           else pl.Float32) 
        for i in cols]
    df.select(*cast_exprs).sink_parquet(f"features_{i}.parquet")
    
with pl.StringCache():
    X=pl.concat([pl.scan_parquet(f"features_{i}.parquet") for i in range(ND)],
                parallel=False, how = 'diagonal')

Another possibility is that you're blowing up your memory by maintaining a StringCache. There are two ways around this, one is to keep everything a String and either never cast it or cast it after the concat. Another idea, is to build up Enums manually. That would be a bit onerous and I'm not sure how much better they are than regular Categoricals on memory so try the above first.
